# SPESENSEのレジスタ操作を行うには？

Tags: c++, spresense, arduino

Arduino IDE 1.8.13の環境で、SPESENSEのレジスタを直接操作したいと考えております。

以下の公式の開発ガイドのFast digital I/Oを読みました。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_fast_digital_io

Arduinoでは `byte input = PINB | ~0b00000011;` のようにレジスタを操作し、
D8ピンとD9ピンの入力を **同時に読み取っていた** のですが、SPESENSEではどのようにプログラムすれば良いでしょうか？
レジスタの設定が分かれば自分でもプログラムできるのですが...
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @kzzさん、リンクありがとうございました。User Manualにそれらしい記述がありましたが、やはり仰る通り、GPIOはピンごとにレジスタが分かれているようです。ひとまず１ピンずつ読み取って、あとで合成するようにプログラムしてみます。アドバイス頂きまして助かりました！

Answer (score 0):

レジスタ仕様はLSIのUser Manualに載っていると思います。
https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products/smart-sensing/spresense/

このマニュアルとSpresense SDKのソースコードをみると、
GPIOはピンごとに一つのレジスタに分かれているので、同時に読み出すことはできないと思います。

マルチコアなのでコアごとに独立してピンを操作できるようにレジスタが分かれているのかもしれません。